# what the difference between sparksessioncatalog and sparkcatalog in iceberg

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

As the title says.
question comes from:
I connect to spark-sql with iceberg catalog like this:

```
bin/spark-sql \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.ice_test2=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.ice_test2.type=hive \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.ice_test2.uri=thrift://xxxxxxx:9083
```

but when I execute `use ice_test2.default;`,I got an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Delegated SessionCatalog is missing. Please make sure your are replacing Spark's default catalog, named 'spark_catalog'.
```

while I run spark-sql with SparkCatalog instead is OK.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit following original question edit:*

The way `org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog` works is by first trying to load an iceberg table with the given identifier and then falling back the default catalog behaviour for this session catalog.
Since you are using `ice_test2` as your catalog it doesn't know which SessionCatalog to fallback to.
As the error indicates if you will use `spark_catalog` instead of `ice_test2` it should work.

Quoting [Iceberg documentation](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-configuration/#catalogs) for more information about the difference between Iceberg's `SparkCatalog` and `SparkSessionCatalog`

- `org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog` -  supports a Hive Metastore or a Hadoop warehouse as a catalog
- `org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog` -  adds support for Iceberg tables to Spark’s built-in catalog, and delegates to the built-in catalog for non-Iceberg tables

Comment: Can you speak it with a technology way？

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?  


Both Catalogs eventually extend Spark's Catalog interfaces (StagingTableCatalog, ProcedureCatalog, SupportsNamespaces)

The difference is that while SparkCatalog takes only into account iceberg tables the SparkSessionCatalog enables you to load non iceberg tables you may have already defined (such as hive tables for example)

Comment: Add more message about my doubt.@Guy

Comment: The reason for the error is because the way `org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog` works is by trying to first load the iceberg table and then falling back the default catalog behaviour for this session catalog.

Since you are using `ice_test2` as your catalog it doesn't know which SessionCatalog to fallback to.

As the error indicates if you will use `spark_catalog` instead of `ice_test2` it should work.

Comment: Your words mean I can access the iceberg table by default while I use spark_catalog in connection config. But not use `use` command to change to another namespace?

Answer (score -2):

1. change  `spark.sql.catalog.ice_test2=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog` to `spark.sql.catalog.ice_test2=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog`
2. delete `spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions`

refferred by   https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-configuration/#catalogs